# How to align Snap's HOME with Linux?

Tags: snap, home-directory

**Background**

When I use n3dr, it looks by default in the home folder for a `.n3dr.yaml` file. When a snap package is created, the tool complains that it cannot find the file. It turned out that snap has an other definition regarding `$HOME`.

`$HOME` on linux:

```
~/user, i.e. /home/user
```

snap:

```
INFO[0000] Home folder: '/home/user/snap/n3dr/x1'
```

**Aim**

To prevent that users have to create a `n3dr.yaml` file in another home directory, the question is whether it is possible to overwrite the Snap's `$HOME` variable to ensure that it is identical to the Linux' `$HOME` default.

How to align this? I.e.:

```
INFO[0000] Home folder: '/home/user'
```

instead of:

```
INFO[0000] Home folder: '/home/user/snap/n3dr/x1'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the snapcraft.io web site:

> HOME This environment variable is re-written by snapd so that each
> snap appears to have a dedicated home directory that is a subdirectory
> of the real home directory.

Perhaps you can get where you want by making n3dr more snap-aware, or by creating a sym-link from the ~user/.n3dr.yaml to the snapd home for n3dr.

`ln -sf /home/user/snap/n3dr/x1/.n3dr.yaml /home/user`